# \NG package conflict

Tags: macros, packages

I have a package conflict resulting from a custom command in an .sty file I am using. The command looks like this:

```
`\newcommand\NG[1]{Gram.: {#1}}%Note Grammar
```

Now, if I run pdflatex it gives me the following error message:!

```
LaTeX Error: Command \NG already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.38 \newcommand\NG[1]{Gram.: {#1}}
                                   %Note Grammar
?
```

Obviously, because `\NG` already gives me the large hooked N symbol.
Is there a fast and simple way to deactivate the symbol command. I don't need the symbol, I do; however, need the custom command. Unfortunately; I don't know which package the clash is caused by, although I would guess either babel, inputenc, or tipa. Here's a list of what I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.3cm, twocolumn, columnsep=.3cm, driver=dvips]{geometry}

\usepackage{dict}%use the style file
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{paralist}%for the \compactdesc environment
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `\NG` for that, change the name for your macro. You'll regret disabling the standard `\NG` command as soon as an author of a paper you cite has a name containing `Ŋ`.

Comment: The \NG marker comes from a perl script, I could change it there, but I don't want to, for reasons of consistency. I can determine; however, that I will not be needing Ŋ.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want your command simply use

```
\renewcommand\NG
```

instead of

```
\newcommand\NG
```

`\NG` is defined in the latex format, not in any of the packages you load, so apply some caution before defining standard latex commands....

Comment: This gives me an output without an errormessage. But unfortunately with Ŋ, rather than with what I defined `\NG` to be (namely: `Gram.: {#1}`). Are we talking about changing `\newcommand` into `\renewcommand` within the .sty file?

Comment: @Lucas Hard to say without a usable example, but if you load your dict.sty after fontenc I don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: Loading it after fontenc did the trick. Thanks a lot David! Solved!